# Enforce HTTPS on a site folder

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, https

As the title suggests is there any easy way to enforce HTTPS for certain site folders.

I am hoping that there is a solution to this using web.config settings.

We are using IIS 6 and ASP.NET Webforms and .NET 4.0

Does any one have any ideas or could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<system.webServer>     
  <rewrite>         
    <rules>             
      <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">           
        <match url="/yourfolder/(.*)"/>                 
        <conditions>                     
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>                 
        </conditions>                 
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>             
      </rule>         
    </rules>     
  </rewrite> 
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I assume this requires a url rewrite module?

We are currently using some of the built in .net 4 routing functionality:

routes.Add("Route", new Route("section/{*path}", new ForceHttpsRouteHandler()));

The above doesnt seem to work correctly as if there is a physical file then that seems to override the route but surley there is either a way to solve this or a similar way to do this without installing additional iis modules?

Comment: Ok, seems to be all working using your approach but with the new .net 4 routing bits.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This helps you http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/ssl_enabling_owa_2003.html